# Add a counter meeting specific conditions

Tags: r, row, counter

**Problem Statement**

Given the below data set which has two columns `Column1` & `Column 2`, add another two more column called `Counter` and `Counting time`. The conditions to Initialize the `counter` and `Counter time` is as follows:

1. The counter should be incremented only when value in `Column1 > 1` and `Column2 = 0`
2. The Counter must start to increment after 2 values from the condition satisfied row
3. The `Counting time` must contain the values of number of time the sequence has occurred (Sequence of data points that has satisfied the condition)

**Data Frame with Expected output**

```
Column1 Column2 Counter Counter_Time  
1.1254  2.784    0        0
4.678   7.985    0        0  
8.89      0      0        1
7.65      0      0        1  
3.54      0      1        1  
4.32      0      2        1  
9.83      0      3        1
3.86     4.3     0        1
5.63     9.8     0        1
4.53      0      0        2
6.83      0      0        2   
3.431     0      4        2
8.976     0      5        2
9.864     0      6        2
7.3      9.2     0        2
2.3      3.2     0        2
4.3       0      0        3
2.1       0      0        3
4.32      0      7        3
```

I came across similar kind of question got the answer on how to increment the counter but I wasn't able to satisfy the above mentioned conditions.  Please note that the Counter should start after the two rows which satisfies the condition.

**Observation from the Data Set**

1. The row number 3 satisfies the condition, The `counter` is not initialized but `Counter_Time` has been incremented
2. The `Counter` has started from the row number 5(According to condition first 2 row from the condition satisfied values should not trigger the counter)
3. Counter in Row number 8 comes back to 0 and `Counter_Time` remains same
4. Again, the `Counter` has started to increment from row number 12 by not considering the row 10 and 11. But `Counter_time` was incremented at row 10

I have elaborated the problem statement so that it is clear to the experts to provide accurate solutions.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? It's good that you have thought carefully about the problem, but people on SO should not be doing your homework for you.

Comment: @Marius No,  this is a part of my project work of Vehicle Prognostics, This is just a sample data frame but my actual data is about 500K values, I know this can be implemented using for loops but I came to know from one of the similar posts that for loops are slower in R. Hence I thoughts of asking experts for the logic and optimized script so that I can improve on that.

Comment: @Marius Respected Sir/Madam, and If you think this is a kind of beginner level question / like problems given to children for doing homework, Then this is  my kind request to please let me know the solution. I accept that I am a beginner for R programming, I have started coding in R from past couple of days and I think reaching out to experts for the guidance is not wrong.

Comment: I wasn't implying this was a beginner level question, your question was just phrased a bit like a homework question (and I'm happy to accept that it isn't). Asking for help is fine whether you're a beginner or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create example data frame
dt <- fread("Column1 Column2
1.1254  2.784
4.678   7.985 
8.89      0
7.65      0  
3.54      0
4.32      0  
9.83      0
3.86     4.3
5.63     9.8
4.53      0
6.83      0  
3.431     0
8.976     0
9.864     0
7.3      9.2
2.3      3.2
4.3       0
2.1       0
4.32      0  ")

### Create Counter_Time
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Merge_ID = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(Condition = ifelse(Column1 > 1 & Column2 == 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(ID = rleid(Condition)) %>%
  mutate(Counter_Time = ifelse(Condition == 0, (ID - 1)/2, ID/2))

### Create Counter
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  group_by(Counter_Time) %>%
  slice(3:n()) %>%
  filter(Condition == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Counter = 1:n()) %>%
  select(Merge_ID, Counter)

### Merge dt2 and dt3 together, dt4 is the final output
dt4 <- dt2 %>%
  left_join(dt3, by = "Merge_ID") %>%
  mutate(Counter = ifelse(is.na(Counter), 0, Counter)) %>%
  select(Column1, Column2, Counter, Counter_Time)
```

#### Update

The following code is an update after `dt2` is created. The idea is to make sure when no rows meet the condition, the code still generates an output with `Counter` all equals to 0.

```
### Set the index
begin_index <- 3

### Filter the right condition
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  group_by(Counter_Time) %>%
  slice(begin_index:n()) %>%
  filter(Condition == 1) %>%
  ungroup() 


### Check if dt3 has any rows
if (nrow(dt3) > 0){

  dt3 <- dt3 %>%
    mutate(Counter = 1:n()) %>%
    select(Merge_ID, Counter)

  ### Merge dt2 and dt3 together, dt4 is the final output
  dt4 <- dt2 %>%
    left_join(dt3, by = "Merge_ID") %>%
    mutate(Counter = ifelse(is.na(Counter), 0, Counter)) %>%
    select(Column1, Column2, Counter, Counter_Time)

### If nrow(dt3) is 0, no rows meet the condition
} else {

  ### Create Counter column from dt2
  dt4 <- dt2 %>%
    mutate(Counter = 0) %>%
    select(Column1, Column2, Counter, Counter_Time)

}
```

Comment: If I want to increase the slice value like 800 and above the program fails, could you please explain the reason for this.

Comment: The reason I am requesting for explanation is that, according to my understanding the value of `slice` will give the number of rows not to be considered(Reference: Condition 2 of the above question), this value will be given by the other variable from the previous scripts. Your explanation will be helpful for the further development of the code.

Comment: @Tareva I guess not all groups in `Counter_Time` have more than `800` records, so the program fails.

Comment: So, do you suggest any workarounds? Because in the final R script both the `Slice` value and the number of records in the data set will be fed as variables i.e Number of groups in `Counter_Time` and `Slice` value wont be static in nature.

Comment: @Tareva I am not clear what is your expected output at this point. If one of the group condition is smaller than 800, would `Counter` becomes all `0` for that group?

Comment: No No!! In your code `slice(3:n())` , this skips 2 data points and starts the Counter to increment. Please correct me if I am wrong. Now if I want to increment counter after 10 values I need to change it to `slice(11:n())`. Similarly if I want to increment counter after 800 values I should change it to `slice(800:n())`. If I do that I am getting an error saying ** mutate_int(2) : Expected only 0 or 1** . Do let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @ Are you sure all groups have records larger than `800`? If not, there are not enough rows to `slice`. So it fails.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. All groups in the data set will always have records larger than 1K.

Comment: I just changed my code to `slice(800:n())`. It didn't break. The last row of each group was reported. So even the row numbers are smaller than 800, it will still give you an output. It is thus possible the errors you got were from other sources. Without reproducible examples, it is difficult to figure out what happend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145195/discussion-between-tareva-and-ycw).

Comment: @Tareva Please see my update. I add an `if` and `else` state to make sure the code will not break.

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution with `data.table` (using the same data as @ycw):

```
library(data.table)
dt[, counter := 0
   ][, counter_time := cumsum(c(0,diff(Column1 > 1 & Column2 == 0))==1)
     ][Column1 > 1 & Column2 == 0, counter := c(0,0,rep(1,(.N-2))), by = counter_time
       ][counter == 1, counter := cumsum(counter)]
```

which gives:

```
> dt
    Column1 Column2 counter counter_time
 1:  1.1254   2.784       0            0
 2:  4.6780   7.985       0            0
 3:  8.8900   0.000       0            1
 4:  7.6500   0.000       0            1
 5:  3.5400   0.000       1            1
 6:  4.3200   0.000       2            1
 7:  9.8300   0.000       3            1
 8:  3.8600   4.300       0            1
 9:  5.6300   9.800       0            1
10:  4.5300   0.000       0            2
11:  6.8300   0.000       0            2
12:  3.4310   0.000       4            2
13:  8.9760   0.000       5            2
14:  9.8640   0.000       6            2
15:  7.3000   9.200       0            2
16:  2.3000   3.200       0            2
17:  4.3000   0.000       0            3
18:  2.1000   0.000       0            3
19:  4.3200   0.000       7            3
```

---

**Used data:**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("Column1 Column2
            1.1254  2.784
            4.678   7.985
            8.89      0
            7.65      0
            3.54      0
            4.32      0
            9.83      0
            3.86     4.3
            5.63     9.8
            4.53      0
            6.83      0
            3.431     0
            8.976     0
            9.864     0
            7.3      9.2
            2.3      3.2
            4.3       0
            2.1       0
            4.32      0")
```